# Rewrite this Firebase Web SDK Version 8 syntax into Version 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with Firebase in my React Native app. I've found a quick fix online, but it's written in Firebase Web version 8 syntax:

```
firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true, merge: true });
```

How can I rewrite it in Version 9 syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass your [settings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoresettings.md#firestoresettings_interface) to the [`initializeFirestore(app, settings)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#initializefirestore) method.

As you will read on this doc [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_):

> `initializeFirestore(app, settings)` initializes a new instance of
> Firestore with the provided settings. Can only be called before any
> other function, including `getFirestore()`. If the custom settings are
> empty, this function is equivalent to calling `getFirestore()`.